# Handling many movieclips from library and putting them into object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I created a Shortcuts class that takes in a movieclip and adds a highlight to the icon whenever someone rolls over it.

The chromeshortcut is the class name of the movieclip, but seeing as how there will be several icons, is there a more elegant way of retrieving these mc's from the library into my shortcuts class?

I was thinking of storing an array of all the mc's class names, but is it possible to dynamically instantiate objects using a variable? So, new myclassname();, with myclassname being variable retrieved from an array.

```
import com.Shortcuts;


var aName:MovieClip = new chromeshortcut();

var shortcut:Shortcuts = new Shortcuts(aName);


shortcut.x = 200;
shortcut.y = 200;
addChild(shortcut);
```

The shortcuts class:

```
  package com{

                import flash.display.*;
                import flash.events.*;
                import 

flash.net.*;


        public class Shortcuts extends MovieClip{

            private var highlight:MovieClip;

            public function Shortcuts(icon:MovieClip){

                highlight = new shortcuthighlight();


                highlight.x = highlight.x - highlight.width/2;
                highlight.y = highlight.y - highlight.height/2;
                highlight.visible = false;
                addChild(highlight);

                icon.x = icon.x - icon.width/2;
                icon.y = icon.y - icon.height/2;
                addChild(icon);


                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, addHighlight);
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, removeHighlight);
            }


            public function addHighlight(evt:MouseEvent){

                highlight.visible = true;

            }

            public function removeHighlight(evt:MouseEvent){

                highlight.visible = false;

            }

        }





    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way - instead of passing MovieClips into the Shortcuts class you should just have the MovieClips extend the Shortcuts class.

Comment: do I set my shortcuts class as the base class in the mc properties?

Comment: Ok that works, which bring me to my next question. If I wanted to center the icon how would I do that? Using this.x refers to the container mc and not the graphic inside, which is what I want to manipulate.

Comment: @Adam I don't entirely get the question. If you want the highlight centered on the icon, you have to move the highlight, not the icon. highlight.x = (this.width-highlight.width)/2;